# How to add a decimal to a sub section (list item \ paragraph) in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to create a tiered numbered list in XAML where the numbering of an internal list contains is parent's number.
i.e.

1. Some text

   1.1 sub list item

   1.2 sub list item

   1.3 sub list item

But I cannot find how to do this. The best I am able to get is separately numbered lists:

1. Some text

   1. sub list item
   2. sub list item
   3. sub list item

[the desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idHSD.png)

this is how it looks now:
[only 1. appears and not 1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZI0w.png)

This is the XAML code (I want 1.1 where it says "random text here"):

```
    <List MarkerStyle="Decimal">
                    <ListItem>
                        <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,8,0,8">
                            <Span>
                                <Run>Definitions</Run>
                            </Span>
                        </Paragraph>
                        <List MarkerStyle="Decimal">
                            <ListItem Margin="15,0,0,0">
                                <Paragraph Margin="0,8,0,8">
                                    <Span>
                                        <Run>“</Run>
                                    </Span>
                                    <Span FontWeight="Bold">
                                        <Run>Bug Fix</Run>
                                    </Span>
                                    <Span>
                                        <Run>” "Random text here".</Run>
                                    </Span>
                                </Paragraph>
                           </ListItem>
                       </List>
```

[red arrow points to where the 1.1 should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RMh1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, that's not possible the way you tried to do it, using `MarkerStyle`. All you can achieve this way is nested `List`, and you said that's not what you want.

In my opinion, the best bet is to fake the marker (`MarkerStyle` set to `None` and marker included inside the text) :

```
 <List MarkerStyle="None">
    <ListItem>
        <Paragraph FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,8,0,8">
            <Span>
                <Run>1. Definitions</Run>
            </Span>
        </Paragraph>
        <List MarkerStyle="None">
            <ListItem Margin="15,0,0,0">
                <Paragraph Margin="0,8,0,8">
                    <Span>
                        <Run>“</Run>
                    </Span>
                    <Span FontWeight="Bold">
                        <Run>Bug Fix</Run>
                    </Span>
                    <Span>
                        <Run>”1.1 "Random text here".</Run>
                    </Span>
                </Paragraph>
           </ListItem>
       </List>
    </ListItem>
</List>
```

This is ugly in XAML, but it can be prettier in C# (auto-numbering items when you populate the `List`), i.e :

```
// Autonumber concats "i.j" (or "i." if j is null) and "cxyc" 
l.ListItems.Add(new ListItem(new Paragraph(new Span(new Run(AutoNumber("cxyc",i,j))))));
```

Comment: OK tnx
I see now I can't use the MarkerStyle for that. I'll try adding a table in each LI to achieve what I want